# Using Redis for user lookup table

Tags: node.js, express, redis, nosql

I'm learning Redis, and I'm working with a simple `users` table. I'm interacting with Redis through `node_redis`.

I store each new user like:

```
client = redis.createClient();
client.incr('user_count', function (err, reply) {
    var new_user_id = reply;
    client.lpush('user_ids', new_user_id);
    client.hset('user:' + new_user_id, 'username', req.param('username'), redis.print);
    client.quit();
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

So at this point, I expect my database to look like:

```
user_ids
1
2
```

And

```
user:1 username 'Guy One'
user:2 username 'Guy Two'
```

**This works fine.** But what I'm now stuck on is generating the full table of users. I iterate over the `user_ids`, and for each one, pull out the corresponding `user` hash entry.

This approach, besides seeming very inefficient (an individual query for each user key), is also problematic due to `node_redis` getter calls being performed asynchronously. So each getter has to, in its success callback, call the next getter, etc. A *very* long chain of nested callback getters.

This is what I had initially tried:

```
var usernamesList = new Array();
client.lrange('user_ids', 0, -1, function (err, reply) {
    var userIdsList = (reply == null || reply == undefined) ? new Array() : reply;
    for (var userId in userIdsList) {
        usernamesList.push(client.hget('user:' + userId, 'username'));
    }
    res.render('users', { usernames: usernamesList });
});
```

But as mentioned above, not only is it inefficient, but it *doesn't work*, because the third parameter (currently non-existent) to the `hget()` method should actually be a callback, which should then call `hget()` for the next item in the `userIdsList`, etc.

The *return value* of `hget()` is a boolean value. As a result, my method as written above simply returns an array of: `[true, true]`

So my questions:

1. Is this the right way to perform/architect a full user list and lookup?
2. How can it be improved to deal with the fact that each `hget()` requires a callback?

Answer (score 1):

Iterating over all users this way would require as many round trips as the length of `user_ids`. If you don't plan on using a Redis cluster, you can use `MULTI/EXEC` to send all of these commands at once and have the results sent back in a single response.

```
client.lrange('user_ids', 0, -1, function (err, users) {
    var userIds = users || [],
      pipeline = [];
    userIds.forEach(function (userId) {
      pipeline.hget('user:' + userId, 'username');
    });
    pipeline.exec(function (err, users) {
      res.render('users', { usernames: users);
    });
});
```

If your users table consists of a single field (username), you can use a single hash to store all users.

Set:

```
client.incr('users_count', function (err, count) {
  client.hset('users', count, req.param('username'));
});
```

Look up:

```
client.hgetall('users', function (err, users) {
  res.render('users', users);
});
```

Another approach is to use a lua script but that won't play nicely with a redis cluster since the user keys to be looked up are generated dynamically and a cluster requires that all keys that a server accesses be on the same redis instance.